# Rserve error in rstudio

Tags: r, zoo, rserve

> Rserve()
>   Starting Rserve:
>    /usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD /home/dipti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rserve/libs//Rserve

Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'

Comment: You have not provided a lot context for us to help. Please provide an example of the exact situation that lead to your problem (R version, Rserve version, code that lead to the error, etc).

Answer (score 2):

As the error tells you R requires at least one of the three options, e.g.,

```
Rserve(args="--no-save")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot start Rserve from within Rstudio because this does not start R with `--save`, `--no-save`, or `--vanilla`. The solution is to launch R from the command line with the appropriate command line arguments, and start Rserve from that.